# How do I set a fqdn which exceeds 65 characters?

Tags: centos, aws

I have the requirement for an FQDN which exceeds 65 characters. What's the easiest way to go about this on centos 7?

I've been provided with a root domain name which is roughly 30 characters and my hostnames are typically 40-50. Usually this wouldn't be a problem as the root domains are < 10 characters, but very suddenly it's likely to cause a problem for me.

My first immediate thought was that the FQDN does not include the domain name, but I can't see where this is set and even when I think I have set it right, the fqdn is stripped at 65 characters (does the FQDN include the domain in the character limit?). Furthermore I'm also curious if this is remotely possible without compiling my own kernel which is a last resort.

For example purposes, lets say the domain name I've been provided is: areallongexample.com and my hostname is usually: a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.

This is straight from my system:

```
hostname a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com
hostname: name too long
hostnamectl set-hostname "a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com"  
hostname -f a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.co 
hostname  a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.co
```

Comment: FQDN = Fully Qualified Domain Name. By definition it includes the host name and the associated domain name

Comment: In your example, the hostname would be `a` and the domain name would be `long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com`. Your hostname _cannot_ contain dots, because a dot is what separates a hostname from its domain name

Comment: FQDNs are allowed to go up to 255 bytes in length, and each component 63 bytes in length. Could you clarify how you’re trying to set your hostnames, and where you’re seeing strings cut to 65 characters?

Comment: Straight from my system (excuse the formatting):

```hostname a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com
hostname: name too long```

```hostnamectl set-hostname "a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com"
```
```hostname -f
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.co
hostname 
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.co```

Comment: I've copied your infomation from the comment to the question, where it can be easily seen by everyone

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a hostname containing dots like this one you have shown us

```
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com
```

You can't even have `a.long` for that same reason: it contains a dot. The hostname is the first dotted component of the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name); the domain for that host is then the remainder of your dotted path.

There are also length limits on the component parts (63 bytes - not necessarily characters) and the entire domain path length (255 bytes). The details are in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc1035).

If you have been given `a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields` as a hostname (less than 63 bytes) and a domain name `areallongexample.com`, the hostname is actually `a` and the domain name is `long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com`.

Comment: I've got a root 53 domain ending in the latter. I can set my hostname to anything I like? Whats the www.google.com hostname? www?

Yes lexically speaking, a hostname cannot contain dots according to the RFC - but that doesn't mean you're not able to have dots in it and the kernel decides what the hostname is. See above in the example - when I type hostname; it doesn't cut it at the first dot. Equally if I do hostname -d, I don't end up with the rest.

Comment: The RFCs define what is and isn't permitted. You can ignore the specifications of course, but that doesn't mean it'll interoperate

Answer (score 0):

I've since resolved this. I set my hostname to "a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields" via hostnamectl. Changed /etc/hosts to have the fqdn and the abbreviated version (a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields)

The server prints out the full name when running hostname -f and the abbreviated hostname when doing hostname.

```
[root@a /]# hostnamectl set-hostname a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields
[root@a /]# hostname
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields
[root@a /]# hostname -f
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com
[root@a /]# cat /etc/hosts | grep required
127.0.0.1 a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields
[root@a /]# hostname -f | wc -c
66
```